# cmdshell query Error "not a valid identifier"

Tags: bcp, xp-cmdshell

I've included the entire code

```
USE [JCIHistorianADX2New]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[GetADX2PointsDyn]    Script Date: 10/18/2021 5:45:38 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      FLG
-- Create date: 10/15/2021
-- Description: Process ADX2 Points
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetADX2PointsDyn] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @dSDate datetime = '2021/01/01 00:00:00', 
    @dEDate datetime = '2021/01/01 23:45:00'
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    Create Table #Points
    (
    EMSPointName varchar(100) NOT Null
    );


BULK INSERT #Points
FROM 'C:\Trend Point Map 101521.csv'
WITH
(
    FIRSTROW = 2, -- as 1st one is header
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  --CSV field delimiter
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',   --Use to shift the control to next row
    TABLOCK
)
    -- Insert statements for procedure here

    Alter Table #Points
    Add ID int Identity(1,1)

    DECLARE
        @Init int= 1,
        @NumRows int
        
    SELECT @NumRows= COUNT(*) FROM #Points WHERE ID= @Init
    WHILE @Init<= @NumRows
        BEGIN

            Declare @SQL nvarchar(4000), @cmd nvarchar(4000)

            

            
            Set @SQL = N'SELECT [PointName]
              ,[UTCDateTime]
              ,[ActualValue]
          FROM [dbo].[RawAnalog]

            where UTCDateTime >= @dSDate and UTCDateTime <= @dEDate

            AND Exists(
            Select t.EMSPointName
            from #Points T
            Where t.EMSPointName = [dbo].RawAnalog.PointName)'

            Print 'SQL'
            Print @SQL

    

            set @cmd = N'master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''BCP ' + '"'  + @SQL +'"' + ' queryout  E:\Honeywell\GSA\Test\ADX2Test.txt -c -t, -S (local) -T '''
            --set @cmd = 'BCP + @SQL + QUERYOUT + @path + "ADX2Test.txt" -c -t, -S (local) -T'

            Print 'CMD'
            Print @cmd

            Exec @cmd
            

            SET @Init= @Init + 1
        END
    
    SELECT @dSDate, @dEDate
END
```

Comment: Following your update, it looks like you need to fix the `Exec @cmd` like I have in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

### curious

The error message that you're getting isn't really sensible given the command you've provided.

Every time I've seen someone ask about this message, it's been in dynamic SQL like this:

```
DECLARE 
   @sql nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT [dead_wrong] = 1/0;';
EXEC @sql;
GO
```

Which throws:

> Msg 203, Level 16, State 2, Line 19 The name 'SELECT [dead_wrong] =
> 1/0;' is not a valid identifier.

If you remove the square brackets in the query, you'll get a different error message:

```
DECLARE 
   @sql nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT dead_wrong = 1/0;';

EXEC @sql;
GO
```

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 14 Could not find stored procedure
> 'SELECT dead_wrong = 1/0;'.

But you don't have an `EXEC` in your example code, so you've either omitted necessary details, or you're troubleshooting the wrong thing all together.

If there is dynamic SQL in your query that you've omitted, you might solve the problem by doing this:

```
DECLARE 
   @sql nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT [dead_wrong] = 1/0;';
EXEC (@sql);
```

Or not using the potentially unsafe EXEC method:

```
DECLARE 
   @sql nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT [dead_wrong] = 1/0;';
EXEC sp_executesql 
    @sql;
```

### scoped

The other problem is that it looks like you're trying to reference a #temp table in your BCP query that isn't created within it, again, unless you've omitted some details.

In some contexts you can reference a #temp table created outside of dynamic SQL, but not this one. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE #t (id int);
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT 1/0 from #t;" queryout C:\Temp\ADX2Test.txt -c -t, -S MyServer -d tempdb -T'
```

Will throw this error:

> SQLState = S0002, NativeError = 208 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13
> for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#t'.

But this works fine:

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'BCP "CREATE TABLE #t (id int); SELECT 1/0 from #t;" queryout C:\Temp\ADX2Test.txt -c -t, -S MyServer -d tempdb -T'
```

And this allows us to at least resolve the object name:

> SQLState = 22012, NativeError = 8134 Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
> 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Divide by zero error encountered.

Note that I'm intentionally hitting divide by zero errors here to avoid writing a file I need to clean up later.

Comment: Well I took out all the square brackets and I still get the same error.